# Radio buttons use "image swap" array - how do i change my array to use string values instead?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, forms, radio-button

I have an array:

```
function displayStoneCut(box){

var stonecutPics = new Array(5)
stonecutPics[0] = "images/designform7/design-form-07_type6-2.gif";
stonecutPics[1] = "images/designform7/design-form-07_type6-1.gif";
stonecutPics[2] = "images/designform7/design-form-07_type6-3.gif";
stonecutPics[3] = "images/designform7/design-form-07_type6-4.gif";
stonecutPics[4] = "images/designform7/design-form-07_type6-5.gif";
document.getElementById('stonecutpic').src = stonecutPics[parseInt(box.value)];
}
```

that works with radio buttons

```
<input name="stonecut" type="radio" onClick="displayStoneCut(this);" value="0" >
<input name="stonecut" type="radio" onClick="displayStoneCut(this);" value="1" checked >
```

etc.

to swap images lower down the page here:

```
<img src="images/designform7/design-form-07_type5-1.gif" width="139" height="161" name="stonepic" id="stonepic"/><img src="images/designform7/design-form-07_type6-1.gif" width="168" height="161" name="stonecutpic" id="stonecutpic"/>
```

This is all inside a multipage form (controlled through CSS).
The issue is that when the form is sent (using ASP and JMail) the values come through as 0, 1, 2 and I want these to come through as strings/word values.

What is the best solution? Modify the array, add another value somehow to the radio button or combine another array?

any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I think the retag will get some great answers to this question.  Let me just throw in that the stonecutPics array should be declared outside of the function.  There is no need to redefine all the images each time a click occurs unless if the collection of stonecut images changes.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<input name="stonecut" type="radio" onClick="displayStoneCut(this);" 
    value="images/designform7/design-form-07_type6-2.gif" >
<input name="stonecut" type="radio" onClick="displayStoneCut(this);" 
    value="images/designform7/design-form-07_type6-1.gif" checked >

...
function displayStoneCut(box){
    document.getElementById('stonecutpic').src = box.value;
}
```

The your form would get the value of the image. Which is what you want?